# Jogo da memoria com tag div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Gostaria que apenas a div atual mudasse.
Gostaria de randomizar as divs. Como preceder?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#1').css("background","red");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#2').css("background","red");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#3').css("background","blue");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#4').css("background","blue");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#5').css("background","silver");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#6').css("background","silver");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#7').css("background","pink");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#8').css("background","pink");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#9').css("background","orange");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#10').css("background","orange");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#11').css("background","yellow");
});

$('.cores').click(function() {
 $('#12').css("background","yellow");
});

/*animacao*/
$('.cores').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $('.cores').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       }); 
   });
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color:#121213;
}

div{
 /*tamanho*/
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 border: 2px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #30aaaa;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:50px 20px 10px 40px;
}

div.principal{
 margin-left: 300px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #306080;
 height: 500px;
 width: 700px;

}

div div:hover{
 background-color:#306aaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
 <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="principal">

<div id="1" class="cores"></div>
<div id="2" class="cores"></div>

<div id="3" class="cores"></div>
<div id="4" class="cores"></div>

<div id="5" class="cores"></div>
<div id="6" class="cores"></div>

<div id="7" class="cores"></div>
<div id="8" class="cores"></div>

<div id="9" class="cores"></div>
<div id="10" class="cores"></div>

<div id="11" class="cores"></div>
<div id="12" class="cores"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro pra mim o que está tentando fazer @Vinicius. Quando clicar em cada `div` está alterado a cor de cada elemento..

Comment: Um grande problema é que você postou uma pergunta do tipo: "Eu tenho esse layout, mas não sei como fazer funcionar, façam isso pra mim?" Não foi uma duvida, foi um pedido de suporte técnico :P
Defina um escopo principal para a pergunta, se houver mais duvidas, crie outra pergunta.... a meu ver esta muito ampla

Comment: @marceloBoni, acredito que agora a pergunta ficou mais clara.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema é que você tá usando o mesmo seletor pra todos os eventos de clique. Explicando melhor: **todos os elementos** têm a classe `cores`, então ao clicar em um elemento específico **todos os eventos serão disparados**.

Um das soluções possíveis é alterar todos os seletores pelo id do elemento que vai disparar o clique, exemplo

```
$('#9').click(function() {
    $('#9').css("background","orange");
});
```

Perceba que neste exemplo o seletor `#9`, ou seja, o elemento que tiver o id igual a 9.

Porém, eu acho que seria muito mais fácil ter só um código pra isso e deixar a cor salva num elemento `data-*` no próprio HTML.

Eu aproveitei e fiz uma pequena lógica pra distribuir as cores pelas "casas".

```js
var allColors = [ { cod: 'red', disponivel: 2 },
                  { cod: 'blue', disponivel: 2 },
                  { cod: 'silver', disponivel: 2 },
                  { cod: 'pink', disponivel: 2 },
                  { cod: 'yellow', disponivel: 2 },
                  { cod: 'orange', disponivel: 2 }]

$(document).ready(function(){
  var mainDiv = $('.principal')[0];  
    
  for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    var color = getRandomColor();
    
    var htmlCasa = $('#template').html();
    htmlCasa = htmlCasa.replace('COR', color);
    mainDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlCasa);
  } 
    
  $('.cores').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background", $(this).data('cor'));
  });
});

function getRandomColor() {
  var item = allColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * allColors.length)];  
  item.disponivel -= 1;  
  
  //console.log(item);
  
  if(item.disponivel === 0){
    var index = allColors.indexOf(item);
    allColors.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  return item.cod; 
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #121213;
}

div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #30aaaa;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px 10px 5px 20px;
}

div.principal {
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #306080;
    height: 270px;
    width: 350px;
}

div div:hover {
    background-color: #306aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="template">
     <div class="cores" data-cor="COR"></div>
</script>

<div class="principal">
</div>
```

Comment: Eu acho que o AP estava mesmo a falar disto: http://www.web-games-online.com/memory/ . De qualquer já lhe deste um bom avanço +1, boa resposta

Comment: @jbueno, muito obrigado